# How to know whether a module requires RankNTypes or ExistentialTypes if it is not explicitly mentioned?

Tags: haskell, forall

In the source of the `memocombinators` package, for example, no LANGUAGE pragma is explicitly mentioned and when trying to import it I get errors because the extension which supports the explicit forall statement is not included. How do I know which extension is required in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `memocombinators.cabal` file: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.1/data-memocombinators.cabal